# How do I get the checkboxselectmultiple formfield_overrides to show on both of my models in a manytomany relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

So here is the code that I am working with right now

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Building(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=60)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Charge(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_updated = models.DateField(default='',auto_now=True)
    buildings = models.ManyToManyField(Building)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from rlscharges.models import Charge, Building
from django.db import models
from django.forms import CheckboxSelectMultiple

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }

class BuildingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Charges.building.through

class BuildingAdmin(MyModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name']
    inlines = [BuildingInline]

admin.site.register(Charge, MyModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Building, BuildingAdmin)
```

I basically just want the checkboxselectmultiple to show up on the Charge and Building models admin pages. Right now the checkbox only shows up on the Charge model and the TabularInline shows up on the Building model. Is there a way to get formfield_overrides to apply to the BuildingInline so it shows the checkboxes and not the TabularInline? Or do I need to do something to the relationship of the models? I apologize ahead of time if this is a stupid question, I am just getting started with django.